# Angular 7, POST to .NET Core Web API sending NULLS

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to HTTP POST from an Angular Template form to my Web API in .NET Core 2.0.  It sends with no errors, but the data in SQL has all NULL values (?).  There is no model on the Angular front-end (only in the .NET back-end), but the "newRetireObject" var object matches the SQL.

Here is component.HTML...

```
    <form #calcForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(calcForm)">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="create-date">Create Date</label>
        <input type="text" id="create-date" name="create-date" ngModel #RetireCalculatorCreateDate="ngModel" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="retireSet">Set Date</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" id="retireSet" name="retireSet" ngModel #RetireCalculatorSetDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="retireSet" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="staffID">Staff ID</label>
        <input type="text" id="staffID" name="staffID" ngModel #RetireCalculatorStaffID="ngModel" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="daysForty()">Generate 1</button>       
            <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" name="fortyDaysDate" value="fortyDaysDate" ngModel #RetireCalculatorDay45="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fortyDaysDate" />

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

    </div>

    </form>
```

Here is component.ts...

```
   import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CalculatorService } from '../calculator.service';
    import { add, subtract } from 'add-subtract-date';
    import { NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

        RetireCalculatorCreateDate: any;

     /* tried adding these, did not help   
     RetireCalculatorSetDate: any;
        RetireCalculatorDay45: any;
        RetireCalculatorDay60: any;
        RetireCalculatorDay90: any;
        RetireCalculatorStaffID: any; */




      public fortyDaysDate: any;

      constructor(private calculatorService: CalculatorService) { 
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.RetireCalculatorCreateDate = new Date();

      }

    //Generate date
    public daysForty(): any {
      const d: Date = new Date();
      const fortyDaysBack = subtract(d, 45, "days");

     this.fortyDaysDate = fortyDaysBack;
      console.log('d is ' + d)
      console.log('45 is ' + this.fortyDaysDate)
    }

      onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        var retireDates = form.value;
        var newRetireObject = {
          RetireCalculatorCreateDate: retireDates.RetireRecord,
          RetireCalculatorSetDate: retireDates.RetireCalculatorSetDate,
          RetireCalculatorDay45: retireDates.RetireCalculatorDay45,
          RetireCalculatorDay60: retireDates.RetireCalculatorDay60,
          RetireCalculatorDay90: retireDates.RetireCalculatorDay90,
          RetireCalculatorStaffID: retireDates.RetireCalculatorStaffID,
        }
        this.calculatorService.add(newRetireObject).subscribe
    (data => {console.log('sent ' + data)})
      }

    }
```

Here is service.ts....

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable(

  )

export class CalculatorService {
  private headers: HttpHeaders;
  private accessPointUrl: string = 'http://localhost:52745/api/RetireCalculatorForms';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
   }

  public get() {

    return this.http.get(this.accessPointUrl, {headers: this.headers});
  }

  public add(payload) {
    return this.http.post(this.accessPointUrl, payload, {headers: this.headers});
  }

  public remove(payload) {
    return this.http.delete(this.accessPointUrl + '/' + payload.id, {headers: this.headers});
  }

  public update(payload) {
    return this.http.put(this.accessPointUrl + '/' + payload.id, payload, {headers: this.headers});
  }



}
```

Comment: I'd like to see your api code.  First guess is either your case is wrong or you aren't sending what you think you're sending.  Is the console.log() showing the expected data?  Does the network tab in chrome or firebug or whatever show you the expected http transaction?

Comment: Yes, the controller was receiving a successful request, no errors.  Data was null because I did not match the name attribute with the model name in the HTML. Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal. Since you're using the Template Driven Forms approach, you'll have to add the `name` attribute to each `input` in your form.

Once you do that, that will be available as the field in the `form.value`.

So the value of this form:

```
<form #calcForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(calcForm)">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="create-date">Create Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="create-date" name="RetireRecord" ngModel #RetireCalculatorCreateDate="ngModel" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="retireSet">Set Date</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" id="retireSet" name="RetireCalculatorSetDate" ngModel #RetireCalculatorSetDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="retireSet" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="staffID">Staff ID</label>
      <input type="text" id="staffID" name="staffID" ngModel #RetireCalculatorStaffID="ngModel" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="daysForty()">Generate 1</button>
      <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" name="fortyDaysDate" value="fortyDaysDate" ngModel #RetireCalculatorDay45="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="fortyDaysDate" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Will be an Object, something like:

```
{
  RetireRecord: SOME VALUE,
  RetireCalculatorSetDate: SOME VALUE,
  staffID: SOME VALUE,
  fortyDaysDate: SOME VALUE
}
```

So as you can see, this will still not generate the values for `RetireCalculatorDay60` and `RetireCalculatorDay90`. So you might want to add the input for those as well to your form.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I knew I needed the name attribute, but did not realize it should have the same name.  I'm trying to send the current day/time to the "RetireCalculatorCreateDate" input on init.  You can see my attempt in my code.  It's not working.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured out how get current day/time. Remembered I needed to use... [(ngModel)]="RetireCalculatorCreateDate" (instead of how it is in my code above) in the input tag to bind. Hopefully this is best practice.

Comment: The input controls which are already present in the template don't need to be binded with `[(ngModel)]`. They just need the be given a directive `ngModel` and a name attribute. And then the same name will reflect in the form's field value.